# Cascading dropdown lists update

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a project that uses cascading dropdown lists. I've adopted a method exactly as demonstrated on this page:
[ASP.NET MVC3 Cascading Dropdown List Demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258172/Simple-Implementation-of-MVC-Cascading-Ajax-Drop-D)

It works ok. If I change Dropdown list A, Dropdown list B gets updated. If I change dropdown list B, dropdown list C gets updated.

The issue I have is, when I update dropdown list A, Dropdown list C does not get updated. How do I update Dropdown List B and C, when A is updated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I update Dropdown List B and C, when A is updated?

Dropdown List B already gets updated with the list of subcategories corresponding to the category selection you made in Dropdown List A.

The only problem is with Dropdown List C which stays unchanged. So you could subscribe to the `OnSuccess` event of the AJAX request inside `CategoriesUserControl.cshtml` and simply clear the products dropdown:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "SelectCategory", 
    "CascadingDropDown", 
    new AjaxOptions { 
        UpdateTargetId = "SubCategories", 
        OnSuccess = "(function() { $('#Products').empty(); })();" 
    }
))
{
    ...
}
```